# differentiating between "as soon as" and "when"

Tags: conjunctions

As soon as I arrived home, I opened the door.

When I arrived home. I opened the door.

Do you distinguish or feel any difference between the two semantically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both fulfill the same function - telling us *when* you opened the door. However, "as soon as" is emphatic where as "when" isn't.

Comment: Right, when  you say *as soon as* it means immediately- the first thing you did, you got out of the car and headed straight for the door.  But "*when*" might mean after you put your coat in the closet and let the dog out and sorted the mail.